# Is it worth using PostGIS for simple distance calculations in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm building a Rails application that needs to be able to select records from the database within a certain distance of a specified point on a 2D plane. Currently, the table stores two points (`x` and `y`, both integers), and simple math gives me all of the "matches" for inputs of `a`, `b` (the two points), and `r` (the radius or distance) - `WHERE ((x - :a)^2 + (y - :b)^2) < :r^2`.

PostGIS provides functions for working with distances (`ST_Distance`), but seems to be designed for much more advanced use cases. **Are there any important benefits to using the PostGIS library for simple distance calculation like above?**

Comment: You do know there is a *distance* (`<->`) and *contains*" (`@>`)  operator in "plain" Postgres? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html

Comment: This is my first Postgres project, so I guess I do now. :) And it makes more sense that the PostGIS documentation doesn't talk about these simple cases. I was just looking at the wrong documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS is typically only useful for people working with real-world GIS data, which may have complicated geometries, projections, etc. If you don't need these, then just use the [built-in geometry capabilities](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html).

---

Using PostGIS specifically for you question, use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). The query will look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table,
  (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(388279.5, 4959511.8), 26912) AS poi) AS f
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, poi, 1000);
```

which will get everything from `my_table` using a geometry column named `geom` that are within 1000 m of a projected coordinate using [NAD83 / UTM zone 12N](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26912/).

Comment: OK, so that would be the PostGIS variation of a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion of contains. But that doesn't answer the question of whether or not there is a benefit of using PostGIS for these simple calculations rather than using built in Postgres functions.